# Vector of Date between multiples dates

Tags: r

frames df1 and df2. I want to add to df1 the version column that comes from the df2 dataframe. The condition is that the Date column of df1 is between df2.Date1 and df2.Date, and accordingly bring the corresponding version.

For example, the first date of df1 is `2020-03-25`, it is between `2020-01-01` and `2020-03-25`, therefore the version that corresponds to it is **CZ01**. Thanks for any help.

##### My df1

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1);vec1 <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-12-31'), by="day"), 10)
set.seed(2);vec2 <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-12-31'), by="day"), 5)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 10),rep(2, 5)), Date = c(vec1, vec2)) %>%
       arrange(ID, Date)
   ID       Date
1   1 2020-03-25
2   1 2020-05-08
3   1 2020-06-15
4   1 2020-07-05
5   1 2020-09-26
6   1 2020-10-03
7   1 2020-10-25
8   1 2020-11-02
9   1 2020-11-19
10  1 2020-11-25
11  2 2020-07-16
12  2 2020-09-18
13  2 2020-09-29
14  2 2020-12-06
15  2 2020-12-14
```

##### My df2

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2), Version = c('CZ01','CZ02','CZ03','BX01','BX02'),
                  Date1 = as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2020-03-25','2020-07-02','2020-07-16','2020-10-31')),
                  Date2 = as.Date(c('2020-03-25','2020-07-02','2020-12-31','2020-10-31','2020-12-31')))
df2
  ID Version      Date1      Date2
1  1    CZ01 2020-01-01 2020-03-25
2  1    CZ02 2020-03-25 2020-07-02
3  1    CZ03 2020-07-02 2020-12-31
4  2    BX01 2020-07-16 2020-10-31
5  2    BX02 2020-10-31 2020-12-31
```

##### Expected output

```
   ID       Date Version
1   1 2020-03-25    CZ01
2   1 2020-05-08    CZ02
3   1 2020-06-15    CZ02
4   1 2020-07-05    CZ03
5   1 2020-09-26    CZ03
6   1 2020-10-03    CZ03
7   1 2020-10-25    CZ03
8   1 2020-11-02    CZ03
9   1 2020-11-19    CZ03
10  1 2020-11-25    CZ03
11  2 2020-07-16    BX01
12  2 2020-09-18    BX01
13  2 2020-09-29    BX01
14  2 2020-12-06    BX02
15  2 2020-12-14    BX02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can try a direct non-equi join (with both non-strict inequalities). We'll see that row 1 is repeated:

```r
df2[df1, on = .(ID, Date1 <= Date, Date2 >= Date)
  ][, c("Date", "Date1", "Date2") := .(Date1, NULL, NULL)]
#        ID Version       Date
#     <num>  <char>     <Date>
#  1:     1    CZ01 2020-03-25
#  2:     1    CZ02 2020-03-25
#  3:     1    CZ02 2020-05-08
#  4:     1    CZ02 2020-06-15
#  5:     1    CZ03 2020-07-05
#  6:     1    CZ03 2020-09-26
#  7:     1    CZ03 2020-10-03
#  8:     1    CZ03 2020-10-25
#  9:     1    CZ03 2020-11-02
# 10:     1    CZ03 2020-11-19
# 11:     1    CZ03 2020-11-25
# 12:     2    BX01 2020-07-16
# 13:     2    BX01 2020-09-18
# 14:     2    BX01 2020-09-29
# 15:     2    BX02 2020-12-06
# 16:     2    BX02 2020-12-14
```

This can perhaps be remedied with aggregation (i.e., take the first non-`NA` `Version`), assuming we have a way to identify the original rows uniquely. I'll assume that `ID` and `Date` are unique, we can do

```r
df2[df1, on = .(ID, Date1 <= Date, Date2 >= Date)
  ][, c("Date", "Date1", "Date2") := .(Date1, NULL, NULL)
  ][, .SD[which.min(is.na(Version)),], by = .(ID, Date)]
#        ID       Date Version
#     <num>     <Date>  <char>
#  1:     1 2020-03-25    CZ01
#  2:     1 2020-05-08    CZ02
#  3:     1 2020-06-15    CZ02
#  4:     1 2020-07-05    CZ03
#  5:     1 2020-09-26    CZ03
#  6:     1 2020-10-03    CZ03
#  7:     1 2020-10-25    CZ03
#  8:     1 2020-11-02    CZ03
#  9:     1 2020-11-19    CZ03
# 10:     1 2020-11-25    CZ03
# 11:     2 2020-07-16    BX01
# 12:     2 2020-09-18    BX01
# 13:     2 2020-09-29    BX01
# 14:     2 2020-12-06    BX02
# 15:     2 2020-12-14    BX02
```

---

An alternative approach is the assignment-join using non-equi join columns (which happens to reverse the order of data.table operands), but we run into another concern: since `df1$Date[1]` is the same as `df2$Date2[1]` and `df2$Date1[2]`, that suggests that the non-equi join should be strict `<` on one side and not-strict `>=` on the other. If you do it so that `"CZ01"` is found for the first line, then `df1$Date[11]` will not fit within a range defined in `df2`.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, Version := Version, on = .(ID, Date > Date1, Date <= Date2)]
#        ID       Date Version
#     <num>     <Date>  <char>
#  1:     1 2020-03-25    CZ01
#  2:     1 2020-05-08    CZ02
#  3:     1 2020-06-15    CZ02
#  4:     1 2020-07-05    CZ03
#  5:     1 2020-09-26    CZ03
#  6:     1 2020-10-03    CZ03
#  7:     1 2020-10-25    CZ03
#  8:     1 2020-11-02    CZ03
#  9:     1 2020-11-19    CZ03
# 10:     1 2020-11-25    CZ03
# 11:     2 2020-07-16    <NA>
# 12:     2 2020-09-18    BX01
# 13:     2 2020-09-29    BX01
# 14:     2 2020-12-06    BX02
# 15:     2 2020-12-14    BX02
```

We can fill in the `NA` with

```r
tmp <- df1[is.na(Version),
  ][, Version := NULL
  ][df2, Version := Version, on = .(ID, Date >= Date1, Date <= Date2)]
tmp
#       ID       Date Version
#    <num>     <Date>  <char>
# 1:     2 2020-07-16    BX01

rbindlist(list(df1[ !is.na(Version), ], tmp))
#        ID       Date Version
#     <num>     <Date>  <char>
#  1:     1 2020-03-25    CZ01
#  2:     1 2020-05-08    CZ02
#  3:     1 2020-06-15    CZ02
#  4:     1 2020-07-05    CZ03
#  5:     1 2020-09-26    CZ03
#  6:     1 2020-10-03    CZ03
#  7:     1 2020-10-25    CZ03
#  8:     1 2020-11-02    CZ03
#  9:     1 2020-11-19    CZ03
# 10:     1 2020-11-25    CZ03
# 11:     2 2020-09-18    BX01
# 12:     2 2020-09-29    BX01
# 13:     2 2020-12-06    BX02
# 14:     2 2020-12-14    BX02
# 15:     2 2020-07-16    BX01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution. Here is some notes on how it works:

- I first used `map2` function from `purrr` as I needed to iterate over `ID` and `Date` variables in each row of `df1`
- In the next step I chose all variables of `df2` in each row which are in fact `ID`, `Date1` & `Date2` respectively which is a numeric vector of length 3 with `..1` variable in `pmap` referring to the first and so on
- You may have noticed that I again converted your dates with `as.Date` in `pmap`, that's because when I gathered all columns except for `Version` they are all coerced to `numeric`
- In the end I check whether our `Date` in each row of `df1` falls into any category and also took into account the matching of `ID`s
- Both will result in a logical vector of length 5 and I chose the first one that returns `TRUE` for either of them
- One more thing to take into account is, since some of your `Date` values may fall into more than one categories like the first row I used `[1]` to only choose the first one

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Version = map2(ID, Date, function(a, b) {
    df2$Version[pmap_lgl(df2 %>% select(!Version), ~ between(b, as.Date(..2), as.Date(..3)) &
                       a == ..1)][1]
  }))

   ID       Date Version
1   1 2020-03-25    CZ01
2   1 2020-05-08    CZ02
3   1 2020-06-15    CZ02
4   1 2020-07-05    CZ03
5   1 2020-09-26    CZ03
6   1 2020-10-03    CZ03
7   1 2020-10-25    CZ03
8   1 2020-11-02    CZ03
9   1 2020-11-19    CZ03
10  1 2020-11-25    CZ03
11  2 2020-07-16    BX01
12  2 2020-09-18    BX01
13  2 2020-09-29    BX01
14  2 2020-12-06    BX02
15  2 2020-12-14    BX02
```